# Unable to pair bluetooth speaker "Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists"

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18.04 (32 bit) and I'm having trouble pairing a bluetooth speaker. It has worked before, but after putting the system to sleep and using the speaker with another computer it never seems to want to pair again.

Meanwhile, other computers can pair with and use the speaker with no problems.

- I tried pairing it manually with `bluetoothctl` but I always get a `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists`. I can't say I know what that means.
- I can successfully `remove` the device, but the result is always the same when trying to pair it again.
- The device is not listed when doing `paired-devices`.
- As suggested in other answers I tried restarting pulse audio with `pulseaudio --kill` and `pulseaudio --start`, and tried pairing again. No difference.

How do I find out what's wrong?

Comment: I'd make sure that the speakers don't pair with the other computer (maybe you've already checked that) by watching the output `bluetoothctl` on the other computer.

Comment: My best guess is that the drivers aren't good enough to restore the adapter after suspend (a hard problem). At least that's the case for the Ethernet drivers, which I have systemd restart for me after every resume from suspend. Restarting the machine whenever the problem occurs without touching the speaker will show whether this is the case for Bluetooth as well.

Answer (score 2):

What helped me was to restart the Bluetooth service.

When I did `sudo service bluetooth status` I saw error info in red:

> Unable pair since another pairing is in progress

and another one

> B4:6C:47:53:FF:86: error updating services: Device or resource busy (16)

So I did `sudo service bluetooth restart` and then I was able to pair the device.

Comment: I've been using a oneshot service that does `/etc/init.d/bluetooth restart` after `suspend.target`, so basically the same thing, I think. I assume you're also mainly having the problem after waking from suspend and not immediately after boot?

Comment: Yes, but only with my new Panasonic headphones and not always. Happened 2 times till now.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I [found](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bluetooth-problem-4175628316/#:%7E:text=systemctl%20start%20bluetooth)

```
systemctl start bluetooth
bluetoothctl
power on
agent on
scan on
pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the device to be connected to the trusted list by using `trust 00:00:00:00:00:00` and then try to connect or pair.

Comment: did that but still getting `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists`

Comment: I am stuck on AlreadyExists. The Raspberry Pi thinks there's already a pair, but the target tablet removed the pair. I can't figure out how to reestablish the pair without opening up the Raspberry Pi. If you do this experiment with a cheap Bluetooth speaker the pair comes right back

Answer (score 0):

for me it was needed to just run:

```
bluetoothctl connect <MAC-ADRESS>
```